# How to add white space and " = " sign in XML createElement

Tags: php, xml, dom, createelement, xml-generation

I am using PHP to generate XML file. I have to add space and `=` sign in XML node name like below

```
<a name="someName">someValue</a>
```

but it is showing `Invalid Character` Error when I use code as

```
$parentnode->appendChild($dom->createElement('a name="somName"'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`createElement()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) only accept tag name and text content of tag as parameter and you should use [`setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) to add attribute to element.

```
$element = $dom->createElement("a");
$element->setAttribute("name", "somName");
$parentnode->appendChild($element);
```

You can check result is [demo](https://3v4l.org/l9s4C)